# How To Make My Own Way To Create An Object?

Tags: java

Objects like `Integer`, `String`, `T[]` all have their own unique constructor call. For example, when creating an `Integer`, instead of putting `Integer i = new Integer(5)`, you can instead put `Integer i = 5`. Same for `String` and `arrays`. I want to know if I could make my own unique replacement for constructor calls. I have a class called `Fraction`, where you put a numerator and denominator, and it can do whatever a fraction can do. Right now, this is how I construct it: `Fraction f = new Fraction(3, 4)`, where the numerator is the first argument and the denominator is the second. I'm wondering if I could do something like `Fraction f = 3/4`, where I don't have to call the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to create your own compiler. Check out "auto-boxing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add your own literals. The best you could do is a function that parses a literal string.

```
Fraction f = fraction("3/4");
```

`3/4` will always be the *compile-time constant* `int`  `0`.

Comment: Not wrong but I actually like `new Fraction(3, 4)` better.  The OP is asking for something that isn't really reasonable.